# Distinct vs Group by Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I am having 2 queries, in one of them I am using distinct and in other I am using group by. which is faster distinct or group by also if I have more than 10 columns then which one is faster?

```
select distinct column1, column2
from table
```

```
select column1, column2
from table
group by column1, column2
```

Comment: What does the time of execution say ?

Comment: "which is faster"; well why don't you try? Regardless, you should use what you want: do you want unique results? Use `DISTINCT`. Do you want to aggregate data (`SUM`, `AVG` etc)? Use `GROUP BY`. If you have performance issues this is the wrong place to try to fix it.

Comment: [Performance Surprises and Assumptions : GROUP BY vs. DISTINCT](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/01/t-sql-queries/surprises-assumptions-group-by-distinct)

Comment: As a general rule, I never use DISTINCT in anything but ad hoc code. DISTINCT is slower in certain scenarios but worse yet, it can lead to unexpected results. GROUP BY is a little more verbose but being explicit has the advantages of it's less prone to error, clearer what you are doing to future devs, and is faster in certain scenarios.

Comment: Run your horses.